# Magento 2 how to add custom attributes to the invoice email and invoice PDF

Tags: php, magento2, magento2.2

I have a requirement that I have two attributes in each product i.e.
 1. **is_product_old** 
 2. **if_old_comment**

At the end of **invoice email and invoice pdf**, I need to show **if_old_comment** in case **is_product_old** is **yes** for each product ordered.

My problem is I don't know **which files I should Edit** to customize invoice Email and Invoice pdf.

then at the end of both, I'll get the product list of that order in that invoice

And for each product, I'll show the if_old_comment in case is_product_old is yes for that product.

So I would like to know what files I need to edit for this and function that can help me to get product list for this->invoiceId and how to get the attribute of the productID.

**I am in Magento 2.2.2**

Comment: You should follow this url https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176062/how-to-modify-invoice-email-template-code

Comment: @SumanDey That is in Magento 1.9 I need to know in Magento 2.2

Comment: Sorry for that. You can find your answer [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-customize-email-template-transactional-email-magento-2.html)

Comment: @Suman that I know from backend but my requirement is bit different I want to add my custom attribute to the invoice email template and invoice PDF. the link you shared tells how to add variables that is not my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I answer my own question others may get help from it.

to get the comment in the bottom of email template:

I created two product attributes **is_product_old** and **if_old_comment**

and extended email template for sales like this :

app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/ellyana/Magento_Sales/templates/email

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
<?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
<table class="email-items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="item-info">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items') ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-qty">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty') ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-price">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price') ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
        <?php
            if ($_item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
        ?>
        <tbody>
            <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tfoot class="order-totals">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>
//Here I added my code  
<table>
    <?php 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php
            if ($_item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
        ?>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
                $objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $productId = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku($_item->getSku());
                $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
                $is_refurb =   $product->getAttributeText('is_refurb');     
                if($is_refurb=='Yes'){
            ?>
                    <p><b><?= $product->getRefurbComment(); ?></b></p>
            <?php        
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
// here my code ends

<?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
    <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
    <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
        <br />
        <table class="message-gift">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                    <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                    <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

after adding my cutsom code I got the comment If any added to each product at the bottom of the email template.